# How to generate the current year, month and date using google chart api

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I want to generate the Year, Month and Day inside the google chart API using the foreach method I'm getting the value for the chart. Please help me to solve this problem. I have attached my code as follows:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Time of Day');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Users');

        data.addRows([
            [new Date(2019, 2, 1), 5],[new Date(2019, 2, 2), 5],[new Date(2019, 2, 3), 5],[new Date(2019, 2, 4), 5],[new Date(2019, 2, 5), 5]

            <?php
            foreach($TotPosts as $totPos)
            {
                echo "[new Date(2019, 2, 1), ".$totPos->totUser."],";
            }
            ?>

        ]);

        var options = {
            is3D:true,
            title: 'Rate the Day on a Scale of 1 to 10',
            width: 900,
            height: 500,
            hAxis: {
                format: 'd/M/yy',
                gridlines: {count: 15}
            },
            vAxis: {
                gridlines: {color: 'none'},
                minValue: 0
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

        var button = document.getElementById('change');

        button.onclick = function () {

            // If the format option matches, change it to the new option,
            // if not, reset it to the original format.
            options.hAxis.format === 'M/d/yy' ?
                options.hAxis.format = 'MMM dd, yyyy' :
                options.hAxis.format = 'M/d/yy';

            chart.draw(data, options);
        };
    }
```

Here total user count is coming but I don't know how to generate the Year, Month and Dat here.

Comment: Is [tag:google-apps-script] related in any way?

Comment: not following exactly, but current date = `new Date()`